# Simple Horizontal Javascript Navigation with Prototype

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, menu, prototypejs

I'm trying to implement a simple horizontal navigation menu that just shows a single div for each link.  It is kinda like a dropdown menu but instead of a mouseover triggering a dropdown, an onclick event will trigger the showing of a div.  I want to make sure I am taking the right approach before going too much further, any help is appreciated.  This is what I have so far:

```
    <ul id="settings_nav">
        <li>
          <a>Theme</a>
          <div id="settings_block"><%= render :partial => 'email_password' %></div>
        </li>              
        <li>
          <a href="index.htm">Lists</a>
          <div id="settings_block"><%= render :partial => 'lists' %></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

      window.onload = function(){
        settingsMenuInit('settings_nav')
      }

function settingsMenuInit(settings_nav){
  $(settings_nav).childElements().each(
    function(node){
      node.onclick= function(){ this.next.show() };    
  })  
}
```

Something like that, but I am unsure how to get the div that is currently shown and hide it.  I could iterate through all the childElements and hide each div and then show the one that is being clicked, but maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes FW(T)W:

1. With Prototype and similar libraries, you don't want to hook up event handlers by assigning functions to the element's `onclick` and similar properties; that style has several disadvantages (not least that there can only be one handler for the event on the element). Instead, use Prototype's [`observe`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#observe-class_method) function:

   ```
   someElement.observe('click', functionRefHere);
   // or
   Element.observe(someElementOrID, 'click', functionRefHere);
   ```

   This also lets Prototype work around some IE memory loss bugs for you.
2. You might look at is Prototype's `dom:loaded` event, which happens sooner than `window.onload` (which won't happen until all of your images and other external resources have loaded, which can be a second or two after the page is displayed):

   ```
   document.observe('dom:loaded', initFunctionRefHere);
   ```
3. You can use *event delegation* and just watch your settings_nav element, rather than each child node individually.

   ```
   $(settings_nav).observe('click', handleNavClick);
   function handleNavClick(event) {
       var elm = event.findElement("some CSS selector here");
       if (elm) {
           event.stop();
           // Handle it
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see, `Event#findElement` accepts a CSS selector. It starts with the actual element that was clicked and tries to match that with the selector; if it matches, it returns the element, otherwise it goes to the parent to see if it matches; etc. So with your HTML you might look for a `li` (`event.findElement('li')`) or the link (`event.findElement('a')`).

   But if you want to watch each one individually, they can share a function (as they do in your example):

   ```
   $(settings_nav).childElements().invoke('observe', 'click', handleNavClick);
   function handleNavClick(event) {
       // Prototype makes `this` reference the element being observed, so
       // `this` will be the `li` element in this example.
   }
   ```

   Whether you watch each element individually or use event delegation depends on what you're doing (and personal preference). Whenever anything is likely to *change* (adding and removing navigation `li` elements, for instance) or when there are lots of things to watch, look to event delegation -- it's much easier simpler to deal with changing sets of elements using event delegation and just watching the parent. When dealing with a stable structure of just a few things (as in your example), it may be simpler to just watch the elements individually.
4. Once inside your handler, you can use [`Element#down`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#down-class_method) to find child elements (so from the `li`, you might use `li.down('div')` to find the div), or [`Element#next`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#next-class_method) to get to the next sibling element (e.g., going from the link to the div). Either way, once you have a reference to the div, you can use [`Element#show`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#show-class_method) and [`Element#hide`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#hide-class_method) (or [`Element#toggle`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#toggle-class_method)).
5. I recommend using *named functions* instead of anonymous ones (see my example above). Named functions help your tools (debuggers, browsers showing errors, etc.) help you. Just be sure not to declare a named function *and* use it as an expression (e.g., don't immediately assign it to something):

   ```
   // Don't do this because of browser implementation bugs:
   someElement.observe('click', function elementClickHandler(event) {
       // ...
   });

   // Do this instead:
   someElement.observe('click', elementClickHandler);
   function elementClickHandler(event) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   ...because although you *should* be able to do that according to the spec, in reality various bugs in various browsers make it not work reliably ([article](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/)).

Comment: Nice explanation on how to use prototypejs.
I wonder how much time you have spent to write this(with links to prototypeJs too).
Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: @Hoque: :-) About 15 minutes. Useful way to limber up the brain for a long work day ahead.

Comment: You are like a supersonic. To write 5 lines it usually takes 15 minutes for me. How can I improve(though this is not relevent question)?.I wonder, if you response. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I would like to thank you as well.  This is the most I've ever learned from a response!  This should be a blog post.

Comment: @Hoque: LOL Well, my mother did give me some of the best advice ever when I was in High School: "You're into computers? Take typing."

Comment: @TenJack: Glad that helped. Re blogging: I've been known to: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/ Been planning a post on the pros/cons of event delegation, haven't got 'round to it yet. Too much actual work to do. :-)

Comment: Hey, what about if I want to 're-use' the same div/space for each option...as if I was doing an ajax request and using replace_html?  Should I iterate over and hide every div and then show the one that was clicked or is there a better way?

Comment: @TenJack: I don't quite understand the question. May be worth posting it as its own question, if it's sufficiently different from this one.